# Track what user is doing in FileDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

For a office app that I am making I need the user to select the project folder they want to be working in. I let them do that by using OpenFileDialog which works fine.

But is it possible to track what folders the user is accessing while the OpenFileDialog is open?
 I would like to scan the folder that he opens for an existing folder "05_orders". So that if it is there the code knows enough and can close the OpenFileDialog.

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                string folder = fbd.SelectedPath;


            }
        }
```

I need this because often the user clicks the end folder and then presses  "OK".

I would like the user to be able to click around in folders and I will tell hem when I like the folder he chose.

The main server folder looks like this
[image: main Folders]

Each year folder has a lot of sub folders for all the projects

[image]

these project folders might have some sub numbers that contain the end folder I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: This isn't a site to ask people to do your job, what did you try?

Comment: @marco I do not know if this is possible. I have a working folder picker very simple but I will post it

Comment: From a UX standpoint it feels terrible if the program suddenly closes my dialog when merely just browsing the dialog. What broke? I will wonder... Besides, the default windows dialog doesnt allow for these kind of interventions. Try to scan "known folders" beforehand and when found, don't prompt the user.

Comment: @Fixation there are over a 1000 project folders that all have even more subfolders. I also can not control if he wants to do this local on his PC or on the server. However you are right just closing it feels wrong but I can prompt the user before I do.

Comment: Just closing the dialog will be a nightmare for the user if the actual folder they want is nested in another folder that also happens to have an "05_orders" folder.

Comment: How do you suggest I do it? I can also ask them to type in the project number but then you risk the user making mistakes. So thats why I wanted to let them pick a folder, more visual and less errors